# Capturing overlay tap event on android mapview

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview, polygon

I am working on creating an android app that displays a polygon overlay onto a mapview over the counties of California. I am having no problem drawing the polygons and seeing them on the map.

I would like to be able to capture the tap event for a specific polygon overlay. I have overridden the onTap method of my overlay item. However, whenever the screen is tapped it is always the last overlay object added to the mapview that fires the ontap event. Unfortunately, that isnt always the overlay I need.

I have seen numerious examples of this using OverayItems and ItemizedOverlays but nothing with a custom polygon overlay. Is this just a limitation of the Overlay object? Any solutions or workarounds? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your onTap code?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you find a workaround?